# How to code for a new window

Tags: python, tkinter, new-window

how can I code for a new window? I have a button that creates a new one but I like to code for it and I don't know how. I think I must define the new window in any way but I don't know how to do this because for opening a new window with help of a button you must define the window self, but no name.

Thanks for helping!

I have create the button and its command in this way:

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()

def create_window(): #Definion und Festlegung neues Fenster
    toplevel = Toplevel()
    toplevel.title('result')
    toplevel.geometry('1500x1000')
    toplevel.focus_set()

Button(master, text='forward', command=create_window).pack(padx=5, anchor=N, pady=4)

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code looks like it is already creating a new window.  How is what you want different than what you already have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coding for the new window (or creating widgets in the new window) is similar to how you do it in the main window. Just pass the new window (`toplevel`) as the parent.

Here is an example that creates a `Label` and an `Entry` widgets in the new window.

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk() # Create the main window

def create_window(): #Definion und Festlegung neues Fenster
    toplevel = Toplevel()
    toplevel.title('result')
    toplevel.geometry('1500x1000')

    # Create widges in the new window
    label = tk.Label(toplevel, text="A Label", fg='blue')
    entry = tk.Entry(toplevel)
    label.pack()
    entry.pack()

    toplevel.focus_set()

Button(master, text='forward', command=create_window).pack(padx=5, anchor=N, pady=4)

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: No, I think that's not what I want. I have forgotten to copy this line, sorry. What I want is... hm, just code for the new window. For example create a message flashing in the new window. But thank you. :)

Comment: I've updated the answer to create widgets in the new window. Let me know if that's what you're looking for.